# SQL to Excel connection in VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have created a connection between Excel and SQL Server using a VBA macro but am having some difficulty with the connection string - specifically the Initial Catalog parameter.

When I run the following, my connection is fine and I can copy data into Excel by referring to the full table path ([dbname].[dbo].[tablename]).

{`conn.open = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & Server_Name & ";Trusted_connection=yes"`}

However, when I run a different version of the connection string (below), the connection fails with the following error:

{`"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & Server_Name & ";Initial Catalog=" & Database_Name & ";Trusted_connection=yes"`}

[image: error message]

The error therefore appears to be in the initialising of the target database - I am not an admin user, but don't understand why the login would fail since I have access to the database and can connect to the server fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the `Database_Name`? It says it cannot open it. Is it real? Does it have restrictions?

Comment: Do you need to specify user credentials?

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, rather than "Trusted_Connection=Yes", try "Integrated Security=SSPI"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies - I have now managed to figure out the issue. The database was fine in that it existed and had no restrictions with regards my access. In addition, the access to the server was fine (e.g. in terms of user credentials or SSPI vs trusted connection).

The issue was actually just a really basic error - the database_name variable was stored in square brackets (as it would be referred to in the normal SQL code):

{`database_name = "[database]"`}

Removing the square brackets enabled the code work